# Calculating the magnitude of the vector created by adding two 2D unit vectors

Tags: vector, position, linear-algebra

I have two 2D unit vectors. My goal is to cheaply compute a unit vector that is midway between them. I am presently doing to via adding the two vectors however this does not produce a unit vector and in fact in some cases produces a vector with 0 magnitude (if they are opposites)

My goal is to figure out the magnitude of this midway vector ideally without having to use square root. This will allow me to normalize this midway vector. And it feels like it should be possible given that the two vectors being added are both unit vectors.

I wrote a program to, for every angle, calculate the midway vector and print out its length.
I also for good measure had it print out the dot and the cross products between the two unit vectors hoping there was some relationship visible. I also took the absolute the absolute value of the dot/cross value so that only positive magnitudes were handled.

[image]

Green and blue are dot and cross respectively. Grey is the magnitude of this added vector.

Looking at this graph a few things strike me as odd. First the inflection point is not quite at  but very close to it... somewhere near 3.3. Secondly its curvature doesn't seem to quite match up with cos/sin. Something else is afoot.

The fact that there is a case where there is no normal vector midway between them possible because they are opposites makes me wonder if indeed the only way to calculate this normal vector/the magnitude of their added vector is the traditional way. But I cannot tell.

Comment: You could evaluate the angle between both vectors using ATAN2, divide this angle by 2 and then rotate one of  your vectors by the resulting vector. There is no problem with a zero vector for opposing vectors. But is this special there is the problem that you somehow must decide if you want to rotate your resulting vector by plus or minus 90 degrees.